# Recording with two USB microphones with different input numbers?

Tags: audio, usb, headphones, microphone, midi

I'm trying to record a podcast using two different microphones (after already realising you can't record using 2x the same mic) on my Mac High Sierra. I've tried this with multiple microphones but I always have the same issue. One mic only has "1 input", the other has "2 input" and it affects the way they record sound.

Microphone 1 (Blue Snowball) appears as having "1 in"
Microphone 2 (USB Microphone 2) appears as having "2 ins"

[image: audio midi]

When I create an aggregate device using these mics, microphone 1 records audio only on the left side of the speaker. Microphone 2 records in stereo, coming out equally on both. Instead of having 4 inputs, the aggregate device has 3. All I want is to record myself and my partner on two microphones simultaneously and output in stereo so you can hear both of us in both earphones.

In video tutorials, my exact same Snowball microphone appears on their computers as having 2 inputs. Any ideas?

Stumpy x

Comment: Have you tried creating an aggregated device? I can't confirm if that will work with microphones. As an alternative you could run another program (Audacity) in the background record your second mic, and the first mic through another program.

Comment: See this related question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/295595/119271

Comment: @Allan - I'm not sure that's really relevant. They already have, in effect, USB pre-amps built-into the mics. I'm sure the simplest solution, as you can't persuade an aggregate input to do it at input, would be to just sum the resulting audio file to mono - & save half the bandwidth at the same time. It would, btw, be useful to see relevant images - the current one is showing output & no aggregate device at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I posted that as relevant since aggregating devices do "work" they're often not reliable. The only reliable way I have ever found to aggregate devices is via a mixer designed specifically for the task.  That said, I do admit it's not an answer to the OP's question per se, but rather a different solution to the larger problem.

Comment: @Allan - for sure. One thing they don't appear to be able to do is the simple task of sum to mono at input - it's all just a bit hokey. Fortunately it's something I always deal with in software after that stage, but we'd need to know what the OP is recording to before we could see if that can sum on the way in; or handle stereo/mono inputs in some way that would achieve the same result. We've really only half the required info right now.

Comment: @Tetsujin - *We've really only half the required info right now.* Par for the course!

Comment: I am looking this post over again and I have a couple questions... 1) why are you highlighting the Output when the question is about Input?  2) How many inputs do you see with just the snowball mic connected?

Comment: Also, instead of trying to aggregate inputs, why not use mixing software - [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) is free