# How to increase input mic volume on mac above 100% during live calls like Webex meetings?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

In macOS is there any way to turn up input mic volume above 100% in software? I have turned up all the volume bars everywhere. Is there some software or any other way to do this in live calls specially?

In my case specifically, recently I purchased Sony WH-XB900N which turns out have an issue with low microphone volume rendering my voice very low during calls making it difficult for others to hear me.
In Audio Midi, the output shows 6dB for these headsets while for Mac's default internal mic, it goes up to 12dB. Is there any app or some other way to boost volume input above 100% ?

The volume with headsets is low with mobile devices as well, but it is quite fine with there so mic is not bad overall.

Following question answers similar question for recorded audio files so doesnt suit my needs :[How to boost microphone input volume above 100%?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395702/how-to-boost-microphone-input-volume-above-100)

Comment: In fact, the linked question is the same as this, it just doesn't have a valid answer. tbh, I don't think you'll be able to do this at consumer level. I have all the mentioned apps & more at my disposal here, but the only one I do have that will do the job relies on external hardware - a USB mic pre-amp.