# Macbook Pro headphones port won't pick up my microphone

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, usb, headphones, microphone

VIDEO EXPLAINER: https://streamable.com/1u1xdz

Proud owner of a Macbook Pro:

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
Processor: 3.1 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB

I have a Rode Videomic microphone with a three pole 3.5mm jack on the end of it.

I plug this in. Nothing happens. This isn't TRRS, I'm not angry.

I plug the Rode microphone into a 4 pole splitter, microphone side, this then into my Mac. Nothing happens. This is attempting TRRS - but it isn't complete, I'm not angry.

I plug the Rode microphone into a 4 pole splitter, along with a set of speakers in the headphones side. This I believed would be TRRS, starting to get angry.

I plug the mic into the splitter with another set of headphones that work if they do not go through the 4 pole splitter, plug the whole complete connection into the Mac port. NOTHING HAPPENS. I'M LOSING MY MIND!

Why for the sake of saving 10g in weight and about a cm of side coverage would they make this ridiculously impossible to connect a microphone on its own?!

Please can someone guide me to a solution that doesn't require anything more than having a microphone plugged in. I need to use my microphone to speak and speakers to play music.

But even with a 4 pole splitter it is not possible.

Is it possible to use a usb-c to audio ports adapter so all I require plugging in is the microphone?

They cut all these ports off the laptop, but then you have to buy more, bulkier, uglier connectors and adapters. My desktop looks like a spider web of wires and adapters.

I'm a chill dude, & I look forward to seeing how you have managed to get around this huge inconvenience.

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: What model of MBP and Rode mic, please.

Comment: Good question I will update my Q

Comment: Added to question

Comment: TRRS isn't a single standard, it has many variants. See https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48560/recording-audio-through-3-5mm-jack-on-a-mac [btw, it was closed for being off-topic for that stack, not for being 'wrong']

Comment: There's a question in here, but it's very difficult to identify amidst the emotional commentary.  Please focus on what you have like the specific Mic model, the splitter models, etc.  I watched the video and the sound is so low it's impossible to tell what you're doing/saying.

Comment: Also, as @Tetsujin said, there are different TRRS configs.  Apple switches the ground and mic pins so this is likey your issue.  If you're going to use a high quality mic like that, get a [quality USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) or even a [proper USB mixer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295628/119271).  Don't use the built in microphone input - they're not as great as people think they are.

Comment: Speaking as a pro audio engineer, I'm with @Allan on the external USB pre-amp. I mean, the Røde isn't the most expensive mic on the planet, but it's not a POS either, so you would do it favours with a half-decent USB mic pre. The only issue may be that external mic-pres expect XLR connections [& potentially phantom power, which your Røde doesn't need & can't use.]

Comment: Can you recommend a good usb-c mic pre? Has to be usb-c please c:

Comment: Try one of the big musical box-shifters like [thomann.de](https://www.thomann.de/gb/search_dir.html?sw=usb+interface&smcs=c40f39_5070) for some ideas. You might need to get some additional cabling to manage the small form factor of the Røde mic connectors. I have a similar issue with my camera/mic setup, I have a lav mic which needs phantom… which I then have to squeeze down into my camera body, which wants a mini-jack. It's a juggle, but the end result is worth it. btw, you don't need USB-C for an audio interface, USB-A is plenty fast enough - again, you need to juggle cables.

Comment: & check whether your mic is mono or stereo. There seem to be several models & I didn't check their full spec. You'll need a 2-channel setup if it's stereo.

Answer (score 1):

USB Audio Port Adapters usually work well, but I'd look for "compatible with Mac" in the description just to be sure. Why your TRRS adapters are not working is kinda weird, possibly dust?
After seeing the video - doing exactly what you are doing (but with a lavalier mic) does work for me.
I can only recommend to check for dust or try to use a different adapter.
There are also adapters that are not splitters (they only do mic to 4pin), try getting one of that kind.

(Don't have enough reputation to comment, which is why this is an answer)

Comment: Look at my video I just added to the top of my question.

Comment: Doing exactly what you are doing (but with a lavalier mic) does work for me. I can only recommend to check for dust or try to use a different adapter. There are also adapters that are not splitters (they only do mic to 4pin), try getting one of that kind.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, can you link me your adapter please?

Comment: I can't find the one I am using online, I think it came with the lav mic I am using. Any TRS (female) to TRRS (male) adapter should work.
There's also an official one from Rode - https://www.amazon.com/Rode-SC4-Microphone-Cable-Inches/dp/B00L6C8PN0 but paying that premium is probably not worth it.