# I can't find LINE IN - Audio Input Problem with a Mac Book pro early 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone, recording

I'm trying to record on my Mac book pro early 2015,  but the Line-In port does not appear. I only have the "built in Mic" option. I have plugged different kinds of mini jack in the only in/out port, with the device already turned on...and NADA.

Answer (score 3):

**You don't have a line in.**

Per the [Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?locale=en_US) for your MacBook, it has support for a line out, but not line in.

> Audio
>
> - Stereo speakers
> - Dual microphones
> - 3.5 mm headphone jack
>
>   - Support for Apple iPhone headset with remote and microphone
>   - Support for **audio line out** (digital/analog)

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

To get a Line-In, I suggest using a [USB-DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) or a [USB Mixer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295628/119271) so you can get a proper line level input and output.  In fact, I try not to use any of the built in audio ports due to their poor shielding and "economy grade" components.  You'll get better results with a proper audio interface.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I switched from a Mac 2012 to this and the previous one had it. Crazy- I will buy an external usb adaptor or a Focusrite audio

Comment: If the answer worked, please [vote up and/or accept this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).  It's how you indicate an answer worked for you.

Comment: @allan Wouldn't plugging in a 3.5mm headphone with a built in microphone, act as the line in though? Or are you saying the sound input is inferior to using a USB-DAC/Mixer? I thought all TRRS headphones (3 rings on the headphone jack) would produce the same input quality? I know Macs are compatible with the TRRS standard so it should act as both output and input.